# eslint custom rule - disable specific html elements in jsx syntax

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I would like to know how is it possible to create a custom rule, where I can define fobidden html elements in jsx syntax.

For example, I want to be sure that only `<Button />` and `<Input />` compontents from my ui library are used. If `<input>` or `<button>` html elements are used in `jsx`, eslint should throw an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create an ESLint rule by yourself (e.g. to learn something new) then this won't be helpful and it's certainly out of scope for a StackOverflow question, but if you need it for practical reasons, [there is already a rule that does exactly what you want](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/forbid-elements.md).